# C# >> Something with the numbers get scrambled up

Tags: c#

So this is what happens: I enter a number and what happens is that it writes out only 1 number: 324, like the variable c is getting this value for no reason..

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter a number with change");
        double num = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        num = (int)num;
        int c = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(num);
        while (num != 0)
        {
            num /= 10;
            c++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: What number are you entering? What output are you expecting?

Comment: You mean, as input you enter `324` and `c` become `324`?

Comment: Try and print the values of `num` within your loop. I think the calculation doesn't end when you think it should

Comment: `num` is a variable of type `double` (a floating point number). How many times do you think the `while` loop has to divide `num` by 10 to become zero?

Comment: What is this program **supposed** to do?

Answer (score 9):

This program *should* loop infinitely if `double` could represent every real number. Say you enter in `1`. Then the loop will divide it by 10, leaving `0.1`. Since `0.1` is not equal to `0`, the loop will continue, resulting in `0.01`, etc.

`double`, however, only can support a minimum value of about `5E-324`, so if you get a number that small and try to divide it by 10, you'll get zero.

So your program loops about 324 times, and quits after it gets a small enough number.

Comment: Nice analysis and well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out `num` inside the loop. You'll see it tries to divide by 10 (division like this can never end in `0`) infinitely until it can no longer hold that small of a value and `== 0` will return `true`.

Just because you set `num` to it's rounded value by using `(int)num` doesn't mean it'll behave like an `int` it'll still end up as a fractional when dividing, use an `int` if you want it to be:

```
Console.WriteLine("enter a number with change");
double num = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int num2 = (int)num;
int c = 0;
Console.WriteLine(num2);
while (num2 != 0)
{
    num2 /= 10;
    c++;
}
Console.WriteLine(c);
```